# Displaying several-digits indexes in Python 3 as an argument of matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, string-formatting

I have a program where I display points on a map in an application of the capacited vehicle routing problem. There is a high school (red square marked "Lycée") and a bunch of bus stops in green, with bus stop number `i` carrying `q[i]` students, where q is a dictionary.

Therefore I plot my bus stops with given coordinates so that their capacities appear right next to them like this :

[image]

[The plot result, with double-digit indexes not showing up properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuQAh.png)

The part of the code that's causing me trouble is this line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in arrets: #arrets is the list of bus stops
plt.annotate("$q_{0}={1}$".format(i, q[i]))
```

Apparently the `_{0}` combined with the `$...$` can only pick up the first digit, which is why I end up with a somewhat ugly result when reaching double digits. I know that in Python 2 you could bypass this by using `{...}` so that :

```
plt.annotate('$q_%d=%d$'%(i, q[i]))
```

would become

```
plt.annotate('$q_{%d}=%d$'%(i, q[i]))
```

which returns double-digit indexes without any problems. But the same trick won't work with the new syntax that already uses `{}` ; I tried it already, along with a few guesses like putting two underscores, which caused an error, or using `{0:0=2d}` which only added a zero at the beginning and "pushed" the second digit away.

I can't seem to find any help online about how this whole thing behaves, because it seems like a "hidden" property of `plt.annotate` with the `$` signs. Does anybody then know what syntax could work, in order to have several-digits indexes to make for a better-looking plot ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: The syntax is the same as the latex syntax. In latex `q_12` will result in only the 1 being in the index, so one uses `q_{12}` to have the underscore relate to everything between curly brackets. Python's format also uses curly brackets, so one might be tempted to use `"$q_{{0}}$".format(12)`, but that would just show the 0 literally, so one needs to escape one pair of curly brackets to survive the formatting: `"$q_{{{0}}}$".format(12)`

Comment: Yes, the double brackets is what I did the first time, good idea to use triple brackets though. Thank you for your answer and sorry for making a duplicate by the way, I didn't see the other topic when looking for similar ones.